# CakePHP Element Error Handling Question

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I have my login and registration forms in elements that reference the users controller and login() and register() actions. When I use this element in a modal or on a page controller action, for example, it redirects to the login/registration action page (rather than update the element), when the user has validation errors (model validation, that is).

I realize that I could use Javascript/JQuery validation, but is there any way to have CakePHP's model validation update the element rather than redirect to the original action's page when errors occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this issue in the past with [this PersistentValidation component](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/binarycrafts/2010/01/20/persistentvalidation-keeping-your-validation-data-after-redirects-2). The way you set it up is by including the `PersistentValidation` component in your `UsersController`, and any other controller where you're planning to include the login/register elements.

Your login/registration forms would submit to their respective controller actions. If validation fails, the action would redirect back to the referring page. For example:

```
if (!$validated) {
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

The view invoked by the action to which you redirect will be automagically seeded with the validation errors from the previous request.

This works, behind-the-scenes, by storing the validation errors in a session variable, and retrieving these errors after the redirect, making them available for the current request's views/elements. You could do this yourself, but the component makes it very painless to use.

Comment: One question with this: If I'm using this to create a User, and I'm using the if($this->User->save($this->data)) { [create code] } else { $this->redirect($this->referer()); }, it doesn't redirects to the page the element is on, but it won't show the error messages that are defined in the model. Do you know what's not working here? Thanks! The User login works fine though...

Comment: Have you managed to get this working? I am having the same problem now...It redirects me back but no errors shown!

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. I forgot to add the `$uses` array in the 'hosting' controller (For adding a comment form in a news controller, the 'hosting' controller would be the news controller). Hope it will help others too.