# CakePHP manually attach validation error to form

Tags: validation, cakephp, forms

I want to achieve a quite "delicate" task, so I'll try to give my best in explanations.

I have a news item page where below all the comments I have an add comment form. In terms of actions, in the `News->view()` view I included an element which contains the view of `Comment->add()`. So, the current flow of sending a new comment is: Enter the news item page, fill in the comment form, and press submit. The data is then sent to `CommentsController` to the `add()` action where the currently submitted data is validated. If data is valid, it saves the comment and brings me back to the news item page. If it doesn't validate, it remains in the `CommentsController` `add()` action and renders the `Comment->add()` view together with the errors.

Now, I want, even if the data doesn't validate, to go back to the news item page and display the error and also attach the error div's to the add comment form. How can I achieve this?

Maybe I've done wrong by creating an element containing the same form found at `Comment->add()`, but how else could I include the `Comment->add()` view at the bottom of the `News->view()` view?

I am thankful for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are doing it the cake way, you can just save from the news controller with saveAll (assuming your models are related).

you would just have an array of ['News']['id'] = 123, ['Comment']...

This will allow you to stay in the news controller and do the validation automatically the cake way. You could just have a method like 'comment' in app_controller that the news controller could inherit with some code like $this->{$modelName}->saveAll(...)

Comment: So, you say I add the comments form right into the `News->view()` view and when I press submit save the data for the Comment using the saveAll() method on the NewsController? It will be a bit odd, because the array passed to saveAll() will contain only data for the comment...Anyway, I'll give it a try! Thanks!

Comment: that is why i said you should add ['News']['id'] = 123 to the array, either through a hidden field input('News.id', array('value' => $id)) or in the controller like $this->data['News']['id'] = $this->data['Comment']['news_id'];

Comment: I also tried your method (post the add comment view right into the `News->view()` view and added some code on the `News->view()` action to check whether data from add comment form is valid), but it still doesn't display anything. Why is this so difficult to achieve? I've seen this feature on many sites but I can't find a good reference on how can I do this.

Comment: I also tried the PersistentValidation presented here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370208/cakephp-element-error-handling-question but still couldn't make it work.

Comment: After hours and hours of debugging I finally managed to do this by using the component mentioned above. Thank you very much for your answer and help!